# Magento 2.2.5 - First Name is not visible in Shipping and Billing Address

Tags: magento2, shipping, php-7, magento-2.2.5

My `Magento 2.2.5` Store is not allowing a registered customer to place an order if the customer uses the saved/default billing/Shipping address instead of a different address. The store displays an error saying

"`Please check the shipping address information. First name is a required field`".

[image]

When, the customer use a new address. It allows the user to place an order without any error as follows:

It can be seen that First name is present in this case...
[image]

I have checked the database and It has the first name saved. But on front end it doesn't display the first name in billing and shipping address as follows:

[image]

I have also tried editing the `default billing and shipping address` and when I press the edit button the `first name field is empty`. I tried to fill the first name field and saved the address, but still it is not displaying the first name.

The next time I press edit button the first name field stays empty as follows:

[image]

Any idea what could be reason behind this error. And what can be done to resolve it?

Comment: Have you found it's solution?